# EF code-first - System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, sql-server-2012, ef-code-first

I'm creating a web API project using ef code-first. For simple queries, it runs well. But for queries with lots of joins(currently i'm encountering problem when querying with 4 table joins. Sometimes, even one table query gives out this error), it says

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

The weird thing is, it works fine when i put breakpoints at the 'For Each' query executing the query or at one of the values inside the 'For Each'. When i remove the breakpoints it gives out this error. Why is this happening?

I've already tried putting below code in Configuration.vb file in Migrations folder, but still doesn't work.

```
CommandTimeout = Int32.MaxValue
```

I've also checked the Connection settings in SQL Server. Also doesn't help.

```
Tools -> Options -> Query Execution -> Execution Timeout = 0s
```

I've also changed the channel timeout in IIS to 100000, but it doesn't work as well.

```
 Connections pane -> click the server node -> Sites node -> In Actions pane, click FTP Site Defaults -> Connections -> Control Channel Timeout and Data Channel Timeout and Unauthenticated Timeout i set them to = 100000
```

I'm worried if i had to keep putting breakpoints at each query, what will happen in production stage? Could anyone help me please?

Comment: your breakpoints will not be hit unless you attach debugger

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: that was my answer for your worry that you will have breakpoints in production.

Comment: @T.S. So i have to put breakpoints or not? I tried putting code:  If (Debugger.IsAttached = False) Then  Debugger.Launch()  End If .. but same error same place.

Comment: Why don't you actually handle the exception, write to log `ex.tostring` and see what is going on? what breakpoints? Breakpoints are for debugging only.

Comment: @T.S. I've got it working now. I tried putting the CommandTimeout in my DbContext file that was created when DB tables were migrated to my project(in the Models folder). Sorry for imposing on you. I've tried this from yesterday and only decided to ask today, but things turn out only after i ask >.<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using EF6 with MVC5. So far i haven't meet with an answer that suggests putting the CommandTimeout in the DbContext file that was created during the Code-First migration(importing DB tables from server). So for the sake of others who's in the same boat as me, put below code in the New() constructor in the DbContext.vb file in your Models folder.

```
Me.Database.CommandTimeout = Int32.MaxValue
```

I also put

```
CommandTimeout = Int32.MaxValue
```

in Configurations.vb file in Migrations folder as well. When i tried removing the CommandTimeout in Configurations.vb file, it seemed like the query took longer time to execute.